# NestJS controller not mapped

Tags: javascript, docker, nestjs, typeorm

So I have an API that will be deployed in a docker container. This API has the `authentications` controller, simple and not something special.

When I start up the API in development mode on my local machine, the auth controller will be found and everything is working fine. Same for building and running it on my local machine. But when I'll dockerize the project and run it on a virtual machine, then I'll can't access the auth controller. Every other controller is working finde, but the auth controller doesn't exist.

Looking into the docker logs, no auth controller will be mapped. Both local and builded docker images should contain the same project files.

auth controller:

```
import {
  Controller,
  Post,
  Delete,
  UseGuards,
  Request,
  Body,
} from '@nestjs/common';

import { AuthenticationsService } from './authentications.service';
import { JwtAuthGuard } from '../shared/guards/jwtAuth.guard';
import { SignInDTO } from './dtos/addGraphNodeToGraphByGraphId.dto';

@Controller('authentications')
export class AuthenticationsController {
  constructor(
    private readonly authenticationsService: AuthenticationsService,
  ) {}

  @Post()
  public signIn(@Body() { username, password }: SignInDTO): Promise<string> {
    return this.authenticationsService.signIn(username, password);
  }

  @Delete()
  @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
  public signOut(@Request() request): Promise<void> {
    return this.authenticationsService.signOut(
      request.encodedToken,
      request.user.tokenExpirationSinceEpochInMilliseconds,
    );
  }
}
```

Error:

```
{
    "statusCode": 404,
    "message": "Not Found",
    "error": "Cannot POST /authentications"
}
```

What could cause that the authentications controller will not be mapped?

Comment: If you modify an existing controller, does it repercutes the modification in the docker container ?

Comment: Put code of module which requires this controller into the question. Maybe there is something here. Also which operation systems do you have locally and in docker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found out that some packages from NestJS had version 6 and 7. So they propably interrupted each other. An indicator was this flood of warnings:
[image]

After running `nest update -f` every controller was mapped as it was supposed.

Edit :

As of NestJS version 9, the update command has been removed.

See here : [Migration Guide - CLI](https://docs.nestjs.com/migration-guide#cli)

Answer (score 35):

If you have already tried everything else and nothing worked, try deleting the `dist` folder. That's what worked for me.

Comment: I already found a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62591471/8408576

Comment: The selected answer didn't work for me so, I shared mine just in case anybody else is facing the same thing.

Comment: Thank you, this did it for me.

Comment: turnout my build was not compiling so intellij was just using the last working version :facepalm: thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much I've been stuck for a while on this bug !

Comment: Thank you so much. I almost drove me crazy

Answer (score 7):

Did you put the controller in the module?

```js
@Module({
  controllers: [AuthenticationController],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Yes, I guess if I wouldn't have done that it would also not work on my local machine

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as the OP, but it was because I didn't restart my NestJS server after I added that endpoint to the controller.

Also, I'm used to npm start in other contexts auto-updating the server without restart (React, React Native, I think node?).

Answer (score 0):

did you add it to your app module? The Module of auth.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem on the server I deployed yesterday. After a day of research, I was using the `master` branch, and my code kept pushing to the `dev` branch, so I hope someone can check that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also confirm for typo you're missing the @ for @Module() in any of the affected modules usually the app.module.ts